# Refresh sem atualizar a página com window.history.pushState javascript e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax, url-amigável

Preciso criar um menu que chame dentro de uma div conteúdos de arquivos em php estilo youtube sem refresh na página porem mudando a url, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta antes em  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291311/refresh-sem-atualizar-a-p%C3%A1gina-com-window-history-pushstate-javascript-ou-outro Não adianta ficar postando as mesmas perguntas que isso não vai resolver seu problema. Melhor seria editar a pergunta anterior

Comment: Achei que havia excluído a primeira pergunta, acabei não vendo. Não sei como usar porque nos exemplos que encontrei não tinha nada a ver com o que eu preciso. Alem do mais os posts que deram de certa forma uma ajuda são de 2015 pra traz.